# ionic 3.X: virtual scroll with infinite scroll(i.e changing data set)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using "ionic-angular": "3.2.1" version but Virtual list shows following blank screen after some scrolls.

[image]

I tried by following code.

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list [virtualScroll]="products" approxItemHeight="100px" [virtualTrackBy]="trackProduct">
        <ion-item category-item *virtualItem="let product" (click)="viewProduct(product)">
            <img product-image src="some_url.png" />
            <div prduct-description ellipsize>
            <div product-name ellipsize>{{product.productName || "" | uppercase}}</div>
                <div product-sku ellipsize>SKU# : {{product.sku}}</div>
                <div price>${{product.price}}/Case</div>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)" threshold="100px" #infiniteScroll>
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data...">
        </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

here is relevant ts file code:

```
 /**
  *  This method will be used for virtual scroll.
  * @param index 
  * @param product 
  */
  trackProduct(index, product: Product) {
    console.log(index, product);
    return product.productId;
  }
```

- trackProduct is not getting called.

I also tried without virtualTrackBy directive but nothing work.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure the image URL for that item is valid?

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug which is just fixed! https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/pull/11624

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'products  | async' pipe if 'products' is getting content from a server like firebaselistobservable. With a normal array virtualTrackBy is never called.